# How to properly model data in Apache Cassandra to allow querying by two different fields that are not unique

Tags: database, go, cassandra, nosql, data-modeling

I am developing a simple API in Go using Apache Cassandra and I am wondering what is the best way to represent data that I have.

I have the following struct in Go.

```
type Message struct {
    Id          gocql.UUID `json:"id"`
    Email       string     `json:"email"`
    Title       string     `json:"title"`
    Content     string     `json:"content"`
    Number      int64      `json:"number"`
    DateCreated time.Time  `json:"dateCreated"`
}
```

What is the best way to create a data structure in Cassandra to allow querying by Email and Number which are both **not** unique (Only Id is unique. There can be multiple messages that have the same email and/or number)? Should I create two separate tables to allow querying by those two fields?

For querying by Id I would create table like this:

```
USE some_keyspace;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS messages
(
    id           UUID,
    email        TEXT,
    title        TEXT,
    content      TEXT,
    number.      BIGINT,
    date_created TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Comment: please share all your possible queries. such as `id only`, `email and number`, `email alone`, `number alone` etc etc.

Comment: @Ersoy I would like to query by email alone, number alone and date_created alone (another case where I need to check date_created and return id only. This will be probably best served by separate table).

Comment: One way to do that is to have an additional table where email is the partition key with ID as a clustering column, and have another table that does the same thing for number. That way, you can do a query to get the list of message IDs corresponding to a given email or number.

Comment: @AndySchweig To make sure I understand correctly. I should create two tables with `PRIMARY KEY` as follows: 1. `PRIMARY KEY (email, id)`, 2. `PRIMARY KEY (number, id)`?

Comment: Yes, i think that's the correct way to specifiy it. You want id to be a clustering column. (I'm not a Cassandra expert, but there may be problems if these rows get too wide (i.e., if there are large numbers of messages per email or number).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *best* way?  Create a table for each query you want to serve.  Build the PRIMARY KEY definitions with *both* the column you want to query by and `id` (to ensure uniqueness):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS messages_by_email (
    id           UUID,
    email        TEXT,
    title        TEXT,
    content      TEXT,
    number      BIGINT,
    date_created TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (email,id));

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS messages_by_number (
    ....
    PRIMARY KEY (number,id));
```

When you write a row to these tables, use `BATCH` to ensure atomicity.

```
BEGIN BATCH
    INSERT INTO messages (id,email,number,title,content,date_created)
        VALUES (uuid(),'aaron@dot.com',1,'Hi','Cassandra rocks!',toTimestamp(now()));
    INSERT INTO messages_by_email (id,email,number,title,content,date_created)
        VALUES (uuid(),'aaron@dot.com',1,'Hi','Cassandra rocks!',toTimestamp(now()));
    INSERT INTO messages_by_number (id,email,number,title,content,date_created)
        VALUES (uuid(),'aaron@dot.com',1,'Hi','Cassandra rocks!',toTimestamp(now()));
APPLY BATCH;
```

Comment: This works! Thank you. I am inserting data using `BATCH` like you said.